# Check by program if eth link is up or down on linux o.s. ...and kernel 2.4

Tags: linux, perl, eth0

I need to check the change in the status of eth connection ( link up and link down ) by program ( using c or perl ).
Now I using the keepalive way, but i sometime loose the notification.
Inside the messages files I see the kernel notification of 'eth0 link down' and this note are always correct so I looking for a way, maybe a syscall, to check for the eth status.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the link status (carrier), you can check the file:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier
```

This will show 1 (link is up) or 0 (link is down).

Comment: thanks Khaled, 
I check your note on feodra 8, fedora 10 and redhat 7.3
your answer is ok for the kernel 2.6, but on redhat 7.3 , when I got the kernel 2.4 there isn't the directory /sys.
On thi last distro, I look for similar files named carrier but i didn't found it.
So my new question became, when to detect the line status on distro using kernel 2.4 ?

Comment: I don't have any system with a 2.4 kernel. Anyway, I will try to find another way for such systems.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a workaround for RH73 (**please** don't ask me why I have a bunch of RH73 boxes to hand, in 2010):

```
[madhatta@ms01 madhatta]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Linux release 7.3 (Valhalla)
[madhatta@ms01 madhatta]$ uname -a
Linux ms01.company.com 2.4.20-30.7.legacysmp #1 SMP Fri Feb 20 10:12:55 PST 2004 i686 unknown
[madhatta@ms01 madhatta]$ sudo mii-tool eth0
eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD, link ok
[madhatta@ms01 madhatta]$
```